# ReadToEnd from a TCP Client

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am using utility in c# that helps me connect via telnet on a remote unix server ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MinimalisticTelnet/MinimalisticTelnet.zip ) This utility, uses a function called Write to write in the shell.

```
TcpClient tcpSocket;

public void Write(string cmd)
{
    if (!tcpSocket.Connected) 
        return;
    byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF","\0xFF\0xFF"));
    tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
}
```

An other function is called to read the output :

```
public string Read()
{
    if (!tcpSocket.Connected) 
        return null;
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        ParseTelnet(sb);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
    } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This function does return the output of the command, but since the commands can last very long time, it cannot return all the output that I need since it quits before the execution finishes. I can't do `Thread.Sleep(time)` because the execution time is not constant for all the commands.
Is there any way to force the code to `read the data till the end with TcpClient` ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this :

```
public string WriteCommandOverTcp(string cmd)
{
    string response = "";
    using (NetworkStream stream = tcpSocket.GetStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(cmd);
                // If I comment the line below, the server receives the  first message
                // otherwise it keeps waiting for data
                response = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

I stumbled on the solution when I heard about the NetworkStream API and it was the solution to read a stream till the end from the Network.